# Need help using a 'for loop' extracting data from a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, extract

Just wondering if anyone can help me.

I have created a table, and using Javascript I am extracting all the data and placing it into divs.

```
$(function () {
    $('table').each(function () {
        var output = "",
            table = $(this),
            rowHead = table.find('tbody tr th'),
            rowSubject = table.find('thead tr th:not(:first-child)'),
            rowContent = table.find('tbody tr td'),
            copy = table.clone();

        output += '<div class="mobiled-table">';
        for (i = 0; i < rowHead.length; i++) {
            output += '<div class="head">' + $(rowHead[i]).html() + '</div>';
            for (j = 0; j < rowSubject.length; j++) {
                output += '<div class="subject">' + $(rowSubject[j]).html() + '</div>';
                output += '<div class="content">' + $(rowContent[i]).html() + '</div>';
            }
        }
        output += '</div>';
        $('table').append(output);
    });
});
```

It all works great except the .content class isnt working correctly. I believe I am using the wrong 'for loop' or I need to create another 'for loop'. Please take a look at my codepen and you will see my problem

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrKBf**

I hope someone can help.

Comment: you have not created **`.content`** class in css. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `rowContent` contains the matrix of cells but as a one dimension array, you have to translate (i, j) to a valid index for `rowContent` which is `(i * 4) + j`:

```
rowContent[i]
```

should be replaced by:

```
rowContent[(i*4) + j]
```

Comment: This is brill. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

In a simpler way, you can do like this,

```
var container=$("#container");
$("table tr:not(:first)").each(function() {
    var heading = $(this).find("th").html();
    container.append('<div class="subject">' + heading + '</div>');
    $(this).find("td").each(function(i) {
        container.append('<div class="subject">' + $("table th").eq($(this).index()).html() + '</div>');
        container.append('<div class="content">' + $(this).html() + '</div>');
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/463/)

Comment: Think I will look into this. It looks a lot cleaner than my code. Thanks for your time. Very much appreciated.